# Origin of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

When and where did Riemann and Lebesgue give the well known [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)? A "lemma"  is usually used as a stepping stone to a larger result rather than as a statement of interest by itself. Did Riemann and Lebesgue intend to prove a larger result when they gave this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial answer regarding the when and where with links to the papers.  Riemann proved the Riemann-Lebesgue result for bounded Riemann integrable functions in his habilitation paper ["*Über die Darstellbarkeit einer Function durch eine trigonometrische Reihe*"](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Trig/Trig.pdf).  He wrote the paper in 1853 (presented in 1854), but it was only published posthumously in 1867.  Lebesgue proved the result for $L^1$ functions in his 1903 paper ["*Sur les séries trigonométriques*"](http://proba.jussieu.fr/~mazliak/Lebesgue_1903.pdf), which was published in Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure.